# How to Find Orphaned List Items in Realm

Tags: realm, realm-list

Let's say I have a Realm schema where I have a parent class and kids underneath it in a `List`. Like this:

```
class Parent: Object{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  let kids = List<Kid>()
}

class Kid: Object{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
}
```

Let's say that, over time, whenever a `Kid` was deleted, it was only removed from the `Parent` object and wasn't deleted from the Realm:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let parent = realm.objects(Parent.self)

realm.beginWrite() 

for kid in parent.kids{
  if let index = parent.kids.index(of: kid){
    parent.kids.remove(at: index)
  }
}

try! realm.commitWrite()
```

I know I can delete the `kids` from the Realm in the same write transaction as the removal from the `parent`:

```
let kids = parent.kids
realm.delete(kids)
```

...but I have reasons not to.

Is there a way to query the Realm database for all `kids` that don't belong to a `parent`? For example, if you were to open my Realm, you could see `100` `kid` objects, but if you look at the parents, only `5` of the `kid` objects are actually attached to a `parent` object.

I have a special use case of Realm where I don't actually want to delete the child `List` items unless I know they don't have a parent. Is it possible to query a Realm for all parentless `kid`s?

Comment: This is pretty simple to to do so I added another answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use [LinkingObjects](https://realm.io/docs/swift/4.4.1/api/Structs/LinkingObjects.html) there's no way to query realm for kids without parents *directly*. If it's not too late to change your data model then I would suggest using them.

```
class Parent: Object{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  let kids = List<Kid>()
}

class Kid: Object{
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  let parents = LinkingObjects(fromType: Parent.self, property: "kids")
}
```

When you add a `Kid` to `Parent.kids` realm automatically handles the `Kid.parents` relationship for you. When you delete a `Parent`, `Kid.parents` will be empty (assuming the `Kid` only had one `Parent`). The great thing about `LinkingObjects` is that you can incorporate them into your queries. So to find all `Kid` objects without parents the query would be:

```
func fetchKidsWithoutParents1() -> Results<Kid> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(Kid.self).filter("parents.@count == 0")
}
```

If you don't use `LinkingObjects`, you have to query for all `Kid` objects and all `Parent` objects and see if the `Kid` exists in any `Parent.kids` `List`. There are two downsides to this approach. The first is that that all `Kid` objects will be loaded into memory as you filter them manually. The other is that you can't take advantage of realm notifications because the resulting kids would not be stored in a realm `Result` object. Note that the following example assumes that there are no two `Kid` objects with the same name:

```
func fetchKidsWithoutParents2() -> [Kid] {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let kids = realm.objects(Kid.self)
    let parents = realm.objects(Parent.self)
    return kids.filter { kid in
        parents.filter("SUBQUERY(kids, $kid, $kid.name == %@).@count > 0", kid.name).count == 0
    }
}
```

Comment: That's crazy, I *just* arrived at this same solution and then came and looked here to find the exact thing I was doing. :) I have added `LinkingObjects` in to accomplish this (such a change doesn't even require a Realm migration) so it looks like I'm on track. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I like this answer but it's not entirely accurate. This *there's no way to query realm for kids without parents directly* is not correct. You can easily find kids that have no parents as if you query for them the count of the result will be 0. I show an example in my answer. That being said - this is still a great answer and solution.

Comment: @Jay, perhaps I could have been more precise in my wording. The original question was *Is it possible to query a Realm for all parentless kids?* The way that I interpreted *to query a Realm* was *to run a single query for all parentless kids*. And that's what I meant by *directly*. Unless you use LinkingObjects, you have to query for all kids, then iterate over each kid and filter for the ones that are parentless (there a number of ways to do that such as in your solution below). Perhaps I should have said that you *can* query for parentless kids, but you have to do some manual filtering.

Comment: Gotcha. The question is a little vague there but I think your take on it is probably accurate and LinkingObjects is the way to go. I added an Edit to my question so it can be done 'with a single query' (instead of iterating with multiple queries) but then leaning on Swift (and RAM) to get the end result.

Answer (score 0):

This question is

> Is there a way to query the Realm database for all kids that don't
>   belong to a parent?

Sure! Super easy with one line of code.

```
let results = realm.objects(Parent.self).filter("ANY kids == %@", thisKid)
```

of course, evaluate to see if there are any results

```
if results.count == 0 {
    print("kid: \(thisKid?.name) has no parents.")
} else {
    print("found parents for kid: \(thisKid?.name)")
    for kid in results {
        print(kid)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In the above code, you can iterate over each kid and see if it has a parent and if not remove it. As a challenge, how about some code that will remove all kids that don't have parents instead of iterating. allKids is a realm List.

```
let foundParents = realm.objects(Parent.self).filter("ANY kids IN %@", allKids)
let kidsThatHaveParents: [Kid] = allKids.compactMap { kid in
    let x = foundParents.first { $0.kids.contains( kid ) }
    if x != nil { //this is just for clarity, could be shortened
        return kid
    }
    return nil
}

let haveParentSet = Set(kidsThatHaveParents)
let kidsToCheckSet = Set(allKids)

let kidsToRemove = kidsToCheckSet.subtracting(haveParentSet)
```

the one downside of this is that I utilized a Set to subtract out the kids that have parents. That would load all of the kids into memory, bypassing the lazy loading aspect of realm. Another option would be just just remove each kid that has a parent from the kidsToLook for realm list.